# JavaScript Most Efficient Way to find Object in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can't seem to find an agreed-upon way to find an object in an array of objects by a single field, specifically a large string field such as a Mongo id. For example I have the following array:

```
[
    {
        _id: "55e4a11251e4c7914426xxxx,
        name: 'John'    
    }, {
        _id: "55e4a11251e4c7914426yyyy",
        name: 'Jack
    }
]
```

I now want to create a function to return the object from the array where the _id is equal. I have the following, but it seems like it could be improved upon:

```
function getObject(searchedId, array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i]._id === searchedId) {
            return array[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"but it seems like it could be improved upon"*. Why do you think so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is a linear search and it is probably the best that can be done unless the array is ordered in some way.  If the array is ordered by the _id field, you can perform a binary search on the array which changes the lookup from an O(n) operation to O(log(n)).

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter:

```
function search(searchedId, array){
    var obj = array.filter(function ( obj ) {
        return obj._id === searchedId;
    })[0];
}
```

Note: .filter() is not implemented in IE8, but you easily deal with that using ES5-shim.

Answer (score 0):

This easiest way is by using the [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method

```
var foundObj =  yourObjectArray.find((obj) => { return obj._id == id });
```

Instead of the lambda expression, you can also use a callback function.